# How to change JXGraph grid lines thickness

Tags: java, swing, grid

I want to make graph paper with JXGraph component. I use next methods of JXGraph for grid lines creation: `setMajorX`, `setMinorCountX`, `setMajorY`, `setMinorCountY` as `(1.0, 10, 1.0, 10)`. Finally, I got an incorrect grid:

[grid http://img29.imageshack.us/img29/5761/graphuv.png](http://img29.imageshack.us/img29/5761/graphuv.png).

I have two questions:

- Is there a way to display identical cells?
- Is it possible to change thickness of minor and major lines?

In JXGraph thickness of lines is defined as:

```
private static final float STROKE_AXIS = 1.2f; 
private static final float STROKE_GRID = 1.0f;
```